# Cut files to clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, clipboard

I'm looking for a way to programmatically cut a file to the clipboard, for example, some call to a function in C# that does the same as selecting a file in the [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

After running the program and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in some other folder on the hard drive, the original file would be ***moved*** to the new folder. By looking at Stack Overflow question *[Copy files to clipboard in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211611)*, I know that it's easy to do the copy job, but cutting seems to work different. How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please try the following, translated from *[The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)* article *[Setting the Clipboard File DropList with DropEffect in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/SetDropEffect.aspx)*:

```
byte[] moveEffect = new byte[] {2, 0, 0, 0};
MemoryStream dropEffect = new MemoryStream();
dropEffect.Write(moveEffect, 0, moveEffect.Length);

DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetFileDropList(files);
data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", dropEffect);

Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use `Clipboard.SetFileDropList` and it was throwing an exception, but your method works like a charm!

Comment: @DarkFalcon, thanks for provided answer, this still works - confirmed in Win 10 too :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to see what happens, I replaced the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a [DragDropEffects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdropeffects%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
data.SetData("FileDrop", files);
data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Apparently, it works as a genuine cut rather than a copy! (This was on Windows 7 - I have not tried other operating systems). Unfortunately, it works only coincidentally. For example,

```
data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

does not yield a copy (still a cut). It seems that a non-null causes a cut, a null a copy.

Comment: see my answer, which uses the DragDropEffects enum.

Answer (score 2):

I like to wrap code like this in an API that makes sense. I also like to avoid magic strings of bytes where I can.

I came up with this extension method that solves the mystery that @Keith was facing in his answer, effectively using the `DragDropEffects` enum.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PutFilesOnClipboard(this IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> filesAndFolders, bool moveFilesOnPaste = false)
    {
        var dropEffect = moveFilesOnPaste ? DragDropEffects.Move : DragDropEffects.Copy;

        var droplist = new StringCollection();
        droplist.AddRange(filesAndFolders.Select(x=>x.FullName).ToArray());     

        var data = new DataObject();
        data.SetFileDropList(droplist);
        data.SetData("Preferred Dropeffect", new MemoryStream(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)dropEffect)));
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Preferred DropEffect is case sensitive please correct it