# Programatically pasting files from clipboard: Copy or Move?

Tags: c#, wpf, copy-paste

I'm trying make an WPF application that I could copy/cut and paste files info and it would copy/move them to a special folder. I know I can get the paths of the files being copied/cut with

```
var files = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
```

But I would like to know, do I need to copy or move the files? I've read something about listening to `WM_COPY` and `WM_CUT`. And I tried by hooking a Hwnd hook to my window handel and it didn't work, neither `WM_COPY` nor `WM_CUT` got called. And I tried everyting.

So what's the best way of determining if the files were copied or cut?
And some code examples or links would really help a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: What word do you mean instead of "whther" exactly?  The sentence with that word does not make sense.

Comment: I think the sentence misses a "know" between "to" and "whether" and a "I have to" after that

Comment: also reconsider rewording your question to state the issue that you are having or what you are truly trying to accomplish.. thanks

Comment: The hook will most likely not work in .NET, sorry. Only two global hooks are allowed, and that's not them. Unless the hook isn't global, is the origin of the clipboard action inside your application?

Comment: @Jonathan Henson No. The I'd like the origin to be any application that allows copying files.

Comment: Then you will not be able to install the hook. I know from experience. Windows only allows left and right clicks to be hooked from .NET. You will have to create a win32 dll, then invoke it in your .NET code to capture the hooks if you have to take that approach.

Comment: In fact, as simple as this sounds as an app, just write it with the API in c or c++.

Comment: I currently have it working by listening to a low-level keyboard hook. But I feel a bit wrong as the code I'm using could be heavily abused.

Comment: Yea, if you can find a way to grab the actual cut and copy hooks, that would be optimal.

Comment: If you want to know if a file in clipboard is to copy or move, look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32670/Getting-the-Clipboard-File-DropEffect-in-VB-NET

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste Files from Clipboard with Cut or Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787840/paste-files-from-clipboard-with-cut-or-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078081/939213 backwards. and for copying – substitute 5 for 2.

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking. He wants to capture all copies and cuts to the clipboard from outside his application.

Comment: See the comment where he responded to me asking him this very question.

Comment: This actually works! I had to try it right away. It works perfectly.

Comment: @JonathanHenson I think he's looking for the hooks as a tool to determine whether it was a cut or copy. To view edits – click on the " edited 14 mins ago" to the left of the " asked 42 mins ago".

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to install the hook. I know from experience. Windows only allows left and right clicks to be hooked from .NET. You will have to create a win32 dll, then invoke it in your .NET code to capture the hooks if you have to take that approach.

Or, as simple as this app sounds, just write it using the API anyways in C or C++.

If this is just a small feature in your application and not the application itself, you will either have to find someway to perform the injection and pass it to your .NET app, or you will have to find a way that doesn't involve hooks.