# Paste Files from Clipboard with Cut or Copy

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, copy-paste, cut

The .NET Clipboard class has methods to put files into the clipboard and also define if they should be moved or copied (cut/copy).

But if I want to **paste** files that were copied into the clipboard, I see no way to find out if the file was **cut or copied** with standard Clipboard methods.

Comment: You are not supposed to know, it is an operation that is specific to the app that placed the object on the clipboard.  It is not impossible that such an app will place extra data on the clipboard, so it can do something extra when it is the same app that pastes, but that is entirely implementation specific.  Explorer is probably the best-known example, it doesn't cut until the file actually gets pasted.  This is not otherwise common.

Comment: @HansPassant _"it doesn't cut until the file actually gets pasted"_ Do you care to elaborate on that? I'm not sure I understand you correctly but in the code below, `aMove` is true when files are cut using Explorer (on Win10, at least). Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Just try it yourself, select a file in Explorer and type Ctrl+X.  It doesn't disappear.  Nothing happens until you navigate elsewhere and type Ctrl+V.  Behavior that is sensible, you wouldn't want the file to disappear when you forget to paste, but specific to Explorer.  Compare to, say, Notepad.

Answer (score 9):

The information is stored in a Clipboard data object named "Preferred DropEffect".
A memory stream containing a 4-byte-array contains the enum value for `System.Windows.DragDropEffects`:

```
public static void PasteFilesFromClipboard(string aTargetFolder)
{
    var aFileDropList = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
    if (aFileDropList == null || aFileDropList.Count == 0) return;

    bool aMove = false;

    var aDataDropEffect = Clipboard.GetData("Preferred DropEffect");
    if (aDataDropEffect != null)
    {
            MemoryStream aDropEffect = (MemoryStream)aDataDropEffect;
            byte[] aMoveEffect = new byte[4];
            aDropEffect.Read(aMoveEffect, 0, aMoveEffect.Length);
            var aDragDropEffects = (DragDropEffects)BitConverter.ToInt32(aMoveEffect, 0);
            aMove = aDragDropEffects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    foreach (string aFileName in aFileDropList)
    {
        if (aMove) { } // Move File ...
        else { } // Copy File ...
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum DragDropEffects
{
    Scroll = int.MinValue,
    All = -2147483645,
    None = 0,
    Copy = 1,
    Move = 2,
    Link = 4
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `var effect = (DragDropEffects)BitConverter.ToInt32(moveEffect, 0);`

Comment: it's not actually stored "in the first byte". It's stored as little-endian 32-bit integer. The `Scroll` flag will not be present in that first byte. Also note it's technically a flags enum, meaning you should check the second _bit_, rather than the whole value.

Comment: Thank you both, I changed my code according to René Vogt.