# Add attachments to Lotus Notes mail by C#

Tags: c#, email, lotus

I found answer about how to send Lotus Notes Mail by C# at this website

```
    public void ComposeMemo(String sendto, String subject, String body)
    {
        // instantiate a Notes session and workspace
        Type NotesSession = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesSession");
        Type NotesUIWorkspace = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace");
        Object sess = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesSession);
        Object ws = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesUIWorkspace);

        // open current user's mail file
        String mailServer = (String)NotesSession.InvokeMember("GetEnvironmentString", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sess, new Object[] { "MailServer", true });
        String mailFile = (String)NotesSession.InvokeMember("GetEnvironmentString", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sess, new Object[] { "MailFile", true });
        NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, new Object[] { mailServer, mailFile });
        Object uidb = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("GetCurrentDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, null);
        Object db = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("Database", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, uidb, null);
        Type NotesDatabase = db.GetType();

        // compose a new memo
        Object uidoc = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("ComposeDocument", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, new Object[] { mailServer, mailFile, "Memo", 0, 0, true });
        Type NotesUIDocument = uidoc.GetType();
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "EnterSendTo", sendto });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Subject", subject });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Body", body });

        // bring the Notes window to the front
        String windowTitle = (String)NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("WindowTitle", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, uidoc, null);
        Interaction.AppActivate(windowTitle);
    }
```

How to add attachments to Lotus Notes mail??
Thank you for providing any requested information.

This code I had tried is work!
just add five lines.

```
    public void ComposeMemo(String sendto, String subject, String body)
    {
        // instantiate a Notes session and workspace
        Type NotesSession = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesSession");
        Type NotesUIWorkspace = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace");
        Object sess = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesSession);
        Object ws = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesUIWorkspace);

        // open current user's mail file
        String mailServer = (String)NotesSession.InvokeMember("GetEnvironmentString", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sess, new Object[] { "MailServer", true });
        String mailFile = (String)NotesSession.InvokeMember("GetEnvironmentString", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sess, new Object[] { "MailFile", true });
        NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, new Object[] { mailServer, mailFile });
        Object uidb = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("GetCurrentDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, null);
        Object db = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("Database", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, uidb, null);
        Type NotesDatabase = db.GetType();

        // compose a new memo
        Object uidoc = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("ComposeDocument", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, new Object[] { mailServer, mailFile, "Memo", 0, 0, true });
        Type NotesUIDocument = uidoc.GetType();
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "EnterSendTo", sendto });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Subject", subject });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Body", body });


        StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
        paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\IMG_1066.JPG");
        Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);

        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("GotoField", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Body" });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("Paste", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, null);



        // bring the Notes window to the front
        String windowTitle = (String)NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("WindowTitle", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, uidoc, null);
        Interaction.AppActivate(windowTitle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some information [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/Lotus_IBM/Q_26421684.html) that might help you.

There are pointers for adding an attachment to a memo, but the same class (`NotesUIDocument`) seems to be used.

[from source]

> Workaround #1: Copy the file to the clipboard, then use
>   NotesUIDocument.Paste.  Not my favorite because it obviously destroys
>   anything the user had on the clipboard, but this is pretty easy to do.
>
> Workaround #2: Create the email using only back-end classes, then
>   display it to the user using the NotesUIWorkspace.EditDocument method.
>   I notice puru1981 mentioned using NotesRichTextItem and
>   NotesEmbeddedObject, but I find using richtext a bit clunky.  Instead,
>   I'm using the newer mime classes (NotesMIMEEntity for example).  I
>   don't have any examples using OLE or C#, but here's a COM/VBA solution
>   that you can use to get started.
>
> http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/Lotus_SmartSuite/Lotus_Notes/Q_24468076.html#24575544
>
> A couple of things to keep in mind:
>
> 1) I cannot think of a situation where you would need to call
>   CreatObject.  That is a LotusScript/VB command that should be reserved
>   for extending the client from within.
>
> 2) Only call CreateInstance for NotesSession and NotesUIWorkspace. 
>   Those are the root objects in Notes land.  NotesSession for back-end
>   access, NotesUIWorkspace for GUI access.  All other handles should be
>   obtained from one of these objects or a child thereof.

Comment: I can't see answers. Could you please copy it and post it here?

Comment: If my answer has helped you achieve your results, please mark it as an answer, this way I get rewarded with some points. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is good. But Could you please add code that can realize attachments to mail ? Plz~~
I think it is something like this:
NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Subject", "Subject" });

Comment: ok. First, copy the file to clipboard, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211611/copy-files-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp

Comment: second, use NotesUIDocument.Paste to paste from clipboard to the document.