# How to copy file to clipboard in XamrinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried to write file to xamarin forms and then copy to clipboard but i have no idea how can i copy file to clipboard any help will be appreciated.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Hello Wolkhjkhjkrld");
            String file = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                file = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

So i want to copy that file to clipboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy files to clipboard in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211611/copy-files-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

use [Xamarin Essentials Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/clipboard)

```
await Clipboard.SetTextAsync("Hello World");

var text = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
```

Comment: Yes but thats will work only for text but for example if i want to copy .html file?

Comment: an html file is just text.  But generally you don't copy and paste files on mobile devices.  You can share files, but that does not use the clipboard.